# Liferay Theme - Updating the main.js file

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

In liferay, I created a new theme and working on to move all my js code to main.js file.

Every time I make any change in the main.js file and build the code, the main.js file is reverted back to the original version.

I fruitlessly searched about this on liferay docs for some time, i'd appreciate if anyone can point me a direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your main.js file under _diffs folder of your theme project.

It seems you have kept js file under docroot/js which always gets overwritten on deployment.